# How to update mongodb configure at Docker?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, docker, mongodb-4.0

I am unable to enable security parameter at docker of mongodb at mongod.conf file. So how can I configure any parameter at mongod.conf file?

I found a file inside mongodb container named it as mongod.conf.ori but where it actually configured I did not understan?

I need expert opinion who already worked on it.  Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

There is two different solutions to this problem. If you look [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) at section configuration.

You can configure things with command line parameters OR you can mount some volume to that container, have config file there and just using -f parameter, point your mongod to that file.

Command `docker run -it --rm mongo --help` will give you more information.